# Prints new line after '\0' character in C

Tags: c

I'm currently doing an assignment where we are to recreate three switches of the cat command, -n/-T/-E. We are to compile and enter in two parameters, the switch and the file name. I store the textfile contents into a buffer.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int index = 0;
int number = 1;
int fd, n, e, t;
n = e = t = 0;
char command[5];

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

strcpy(command, argv[1]);
fd = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
if( fd == -1)
{
    perror(argv[2]);
    exit(1);
}

read(fd, buffer,BUFFERSIZE);

if( !strcmp("cat", command)){
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
else if( !strcmp("-n", command)){
    n = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-E", command)){
    e = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-T", command)){
    t = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-nE", command) || !strcmp("-En", command)){
    n = e = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-nT", command) || !strcmp("-Tn", command)){
    n = t = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-ET", command) || !strcmp("-TE", command)){
    t = e = 1;
}
else if( !strcmp("-nET", command) || !strcmp("-nTE", command) || 
      !strcmp("-TnE", command) || !strcmp("-EnT", command) || 
      !strcmp("-ETn", command) || !strcmp("-TEn", command)){
    n = e = t = 1;
}
else{
    printf("Invalid Switch Entry");
}

if(n){
    printf("%d  ", number++); 
}

while(buffer[index++] != '\0' && ( n || e || t)){
    if(buffer[index] == '\n' && e && n){
        printf("$\n%d  ", number++);
    }
    else if(buffer[index] == '\n' && e){
        printf("$\n");
    }
    else if(buffer[index] == '\t' && t){
        printf("^I");
    }
    else if(buffer[index] == '\n' && n){
        printf("\n%d  ", number++);
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", buffer[index]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
close(fd);
return 0;
```

}

Everything works perfectly except when I try to use the -n command. It adds an extra new line. I use a textfile that has

```
hello

 hello

   hello world!
```

instead of

```
1 hello

2  hello

3    hello world!
```

it will print out this:

```
1 hello

2  hello

3    hello world!

4
```

For some reason it adds the extra line after the world!

> Am I missing something simple?

Comment: You print the number of the next line when you print a new-line character. In your example, you print the 4 together with the terminating new-line of line 3. You could postpone printing the newline by keeping a marker whether the last char was a newline and then print the line number. You should threat the imaginary character before the output as a newline in order to catch the first line.

Comment: Note that you incmenet `index` in the `while` condition, which means that you look at the character after the one you checked inside the loop, which might well be the null character. You will also miss the first character in the file; try catting a file that begins with a newline or a tab. Consider using a `for` loop where you increment `index` in the update section.

Comment: I tried your code. It does not print what you post, and the first char of file is cut because of you inc index at the top of while loop.

Answer (score 1):

This might not fix your problem, but I don't see any code to put the terminating null character in `buffer`. Try:

```
// Reserve one character for the null terminator.
ssize_t n = read(fd, buffer, BUFFERSIZE-1);
if ( n == -1  )
{
   // Deal with error.
   printf("Unable to read the contents of the file.\n");
   exit(1); //???
}

buffer[n] = '\0';
```

Comment: Out of bounds write much?

Comment: it only gets worse when you consider `read()` could return `-1` on error.

Comment: Now how do you distinguish an empty file from one containing `"Unable to read the contents of the file."` and a newline? I'd prefer `perror()` to `printf()`.

Comment: @EOF, from the exit status of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The three `cat` options that you implement have different "modes":

- `-T` replaces a character (no tab is written);
- `-E` prepends a character with additional output (the new-line character is still written);
- `-n` prepends each line with additional output.

You can handle the first two modes directly. The third mode requires information from the character before: A new line starts at the start of the file and after a new-line character has been read. So you need a flag to keep track of that.

(Your code prints a line number after a new-line character is found. That means that you have to treat the first line explicitly and that you get one too many line umber at the end. After all, a file with `n` lines has `n` new-line characters and you print `n + 1` line numbers.)

Other issues:

- As R Sahu has pointed out, your input isn't null-terminated. You don't really need a null terminator here: `read` returns the number of bytes read or an error code. You can use that number as limit for `index`.
- You incmenet `index` in the `while` condition, which means that you look at the character after the one you checked inside the loop, which might well be the null character. You will also miss the first character in the file.
- In fact, you don't need a buffer here. When the file is larger than you buffer, you truncate it. You could call `read` in a loop until you read fewer bytes than `BUFFERSIZE`, but the simplest way in this case is to read one byte after the other and process it.
- You use too many compound conditions. This isn't wrong per se, but it makes for complicated code. Your main loop reads like a big `switch` when there are in fact only a few special cases to treat.
- The way you determine the flags is both too complicated and too restricted. You chack all combinations of flags, which is 6 for the case that all flags are given. What if you add another flag? Are you going to write 24 more `strcmps`? Look for the minus sign as first character and then at the letters one by one, setting flags and printing error messages as you go.
- You don't need to copy `argv[1]` to `command`; you are only inspecting it. And you are introducing a source of error: If the second argument is longer than 4 characters, you will get undefined behaviour, very likely a crash.
- If you don't give any options, the file name should be `argv[1]` instead of `argv[2]`.

Putting this (sans the flag parsing) into practice:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[2], "r");
int newline = 1;                    // marker for line numbers

// Error checking

for (;;)
{
    int c = fgetc(f);               // read one character

    if (c == EOF) break;            // terminate loop on end of file

    if (newline) {
        if (n) printf("%5d   ", number++);
        newline = 0;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        newline = 1;
        if (e) putchar('$');
    }

    if (c == '\t' && t) {
        putchar('^');
        putchar('I');
    } else {
        putchar(c);
    }
}

fclose(f);
```

**Edit**: If you are restricted to using the Unix `open`, `close` and `read`, you can still use the approach above. You need an additional loop that reads blocks of a certain size with `read`.  The `read` function returns the value of the bytes read. If that is less than the number of bytes asked for, stop the loop.

The example below adds yet an additional loop that allows to concatenate several files.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 0x400

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int t = 0;

    int number = 0;
    int first = 1;

    while (first < argc && *argv[first] == '-') {
        char *str = argv[first] + 1;

        while (*str) {
            switch (*str) {
            case 'n':   n = 1; break;
            case 'E':   e = 1; break;
            case 'T':   t = 1; break;
            default:    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown switch -%c.\n", *str);
                        exit(0);
            }
            str++;
        }

        first++;
    }

    while (first < argc) {
        int fd = open(argv[first], O_RDONLY);
        int newline = 1;
        int bytes;

        if (fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[first]);
            exit(1);
        }

        do {
            char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
            int i;

            bytes = read(fd, buffer,BUFFERSIZE);

            for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                int c = buffer[i];

                if (newline) {
                    if (n) printf("%5d   ", number++);
                    newline = 0;
                }

                if (c == '\n') {
                    newline = 1;
                    if (e) putchar('$');
                }

                if (c == '\t' && t) {
                    putchar('^');
                    putchar('I');
                } else {
                    putchar(c);
                }
            }            

        } while (bytes == BUFFERSIZE);

        close(fd);
        first++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. The way you structured your code has helped me see a simpler way to implement this. The only thing that I forgot to mention is that we can only use open(), close() and read(). I couldn't use C file I/O functions.

Comment: `read` tells you how many bytes have been read. You can use this information to write a loop that continuously reads blocks of a certain size and stop after an incomplete block was read.